# How to add "Middle Name, Suffix, etc" to the Contact's Name field

Tags: custom-field, contact, fields, defaults

**Goal:** Within a contact, the name field is concatenated in the user view and I would like to add custom fields to this concatenation. Currently, appears this is not possible, though possible I am missing something.

---

**Background:** Within Salesforce it appears that the [name field](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm) is a set of three fields: Prefix, First, Last; documentation say it's just the First, Last - though at least my instance appears to be the Prefix, First, Last.

Also, it appears that this summer, that [Salesforce will be introducing the new default fields](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqVVAA0) to make this: Prefix, First, Middle, Last, Suffix.

> "I'm pleased to announce that we will be offering a sneak peek of
>   Middle Name and Suffix on Leads, Contacts, Person Accounts and Users
>   in our upcoming Summer release. More details to follow on how you can
>   get access to this functionality for your organization." *Blake Markham  - Salesforce, Product Manager*

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Why don't you create just a formula field?

Comment: I don't think that's possible since the `Name` field is one of the "special" system fields. You don't have control over that. You might want to create a custom field as @brovasi mentioned and concatenate any fields you want, then use your custom "Name" field...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to change the formula that "Builds" the standard name field.

You can however create a new custom field with a formula that concatenates the component fields, e.g.:[image]

I used this formula to build the "name examp" at the top of the previous screenshot using the components of the standard name field plus my middle name field (*no doubt someone could write a more elegant formula*):

```
text(Salutation) &" "& FirstName &" "& middlename__c &" "& LastName
```

Of note - you have to use "text" on the Salutation as it's a picklist value.

Comment: +1 Putting aside the fact that you've now posted two answers that appear to be the same solution basically, though each with different pieces of info on the solution - nice answer; that said, upvoted both, grateful for the help. So, nice pic of the solution, and code is clearly of use too. I will give it a go, and report back. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As per previous comments - I would create custom fields for the "middle" and "suffix".

Then create a custom field that concatenates the respective fields.

As far as I'm aware you can't remove the default "Name" field from a page layout(?) so you would end up with both the standard name field and your custom one.

Comment: Thanks, possible that I am misunderstanding something, but believe the formulas are read-only (unlike the Name field) and that the Name field is pretty core to running reports, doing 3rd party integration, etc - right? Also, I am able to confirm that it is not possible to remove the Name field from the Contact layout.